# Highlight multiple fields on validate javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want when *textfields* empty it will highlight it. Following is my code its only highlight one field at one time. If both fields empty it will highlight one field.

```
<script>
function ValidateForm(){

    var summary=document.getElementById("<%=summary.ClientID%>");
    if (summary.value == "" && txtTest.value == "") {
        summary.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        return false;
    }
    var txtTest = document.getElementById("<%=txtTest.ClientID%>");
    if (txtTest.value == "" ) {

        txtTest.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        return false;
    }

   return true;

}
</script>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I don't want to use default validators.

Comment: issue is with your `return false;` statement.. I would suggest you to remove that line and rather keep a flag and update this flag... after your both if checks then check this flag and do a `return false;` or skip it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you are returning false before checking for the second input. you need to return `true` or `false` only after all inputs have been checked.  Also you must first get txtTest before checking for its value. you can do something like this:

```
<script>
function ValidateForm(){

    var validate = true;

    var summary=document.getElementById("<%=summary.ClientID%>");
    if (summary.value == "") {
        summary.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        validate = false;
    }
    var txtTest = document.getElementById("<%=txtTest.ClientID%>");
    if (txtTest.value == "" ) {

        txtTest.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        validate = false;
    }

   return validate;

}
</script>
```

Comment: its not highlighting fields

Answer (score 1):

instead of returning false in error condition use flag to indicate error.

by default flag is true and if there is an  error  it should be set to false.

finally return error flag.

```
 <script>
 function ValidateForm(){
var flag=true;
var summary=document.getElementById("<%=summary.ClientID%>");

if (summary.value == "" && txtTest.value == "") {
    summary.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
    flag=false;
}
var txtTest = document.getElementById("<%=txtTest.ClientID%>");
if (txtTest.value == "" ) {

    txtTest.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
    flag=false;
}

 return flag;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

first you should get txtTest var before evaluating it, 
then instead of returning after each if, do it at bottom for validation

```
var summary=document.getElementById("<%=summary.ClientID%>");
var txtTest = document.getElementById("<%=txtTest.ClientID%>");

if (summary.value == "") {
    summary.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
}

if (txtTest.value == "" ) {
    txtTest.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
}
return !(summary.value == "" || txtTest.value == "")
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach if your form is more complex maybe to separate the validation and highlighting.

```js
// onKeyUp
function k(e) {
 this.style.background = (this.value) ? "none" : "#0f0";
}
window.onload = function() {
  var t = ["in1","in2","in3"];
  var i, max = t.length;
  var d;
  for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
    d = document.getElementById(t[i]);
    d.style.background="#0f0";
    d.addEventListener("keyup",k,false);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in1" name="in1" placeholder="Input 1"/><br />
<input type="text" id="in2" name="in2" placeholder="Input 2"/><br />
<input type="text" id="in3" name="in3" placeholder="Input 3"/><br />
```